# Neither BindingResult Nor Plain Target Object For Bean Name ‘Xxx’ Available As Request Attribute

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting this error, while trying to configure the spring controllers. I am sure that I have the name correctly matching and it still gives me this error. Here is my controller class. Also the input and output page are same. please help me

"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userForm' available as request attribute"

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes
public class UserController {

    protected Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/userList")
    public ModelAndView getUserList(){

        List<User> userList = userService.getUserList();        

        return new ModelAndView("userList", "userList", userList);      
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/findUser")
    public ModelAndView findUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,
                                 BindingResult result){ 

        List<User> userResultsList = null;

        //model.addAttribute("user", new User());

        userResultsList = userService.findUser(user.getUsername(), user.getFirstname(),
                user.getLastname());            

        return new ModelAndView("userList", "user", userResultsList);       
    }


}
```

And my JSP is here

```
<body>
    <form:form modelAttribute="user" method="post" action="/findUser.html">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="username">User ID:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="firstname">First Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="lastname">Last Name:</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="findUser" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>    
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Id</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>Email Address</td>
                <td>Last Update Date</td>
                <td>Last Update By</td>
            </tr>
        <c:forEach var="list" items="${userList}">
            <tr>
                <td>${list.userId}</td>
                <td>${list.username}</td>
                <td>${list.firstname}</td>
                <td>${list.lastname}</td>
                <td>${list.email}</td>
                <td>${list.lastUpdatedBy}</td>
                <td>${list.lastUpdatedDate}</td>    
                <td><a href="listVendors.html?userId=${list.userId}">assignVendor</a></td>          
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following line to your public ModelAndView getUserList() method:

```
modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
```

Comment: I just updated the  return new ModelAndView("userList", "user", userList); userList to 'user' in the above statement and its working now. But its complaining saying its unable to find a property called 'username'. Invalid property 'username' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'username' is not readable or has an invalid getter ?. Do you have any idea about this..

Comment: Try to paste this code: ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("userList"); view.addObject("user", new User()); view.addObject("userList", userList); return view;
You must add two objects: first is empty User object, second - userList, List of users

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP you are using two model attributes, named "user" and "userList", which are basically properties of the MODEL object.

When you first come to the page, Spring will try to find the property values with names "user" and "userList" from the Model object (the M in MVC). So you need to set the property values for "user" and "userList" before showing the page to the user (typically from within the method that takes the user to the JSP page), and in your case you can do that by changing the "getUSerList" method as follows:

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/userList")
        public ModelAndView getUserList(){
             ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("userList");
             User user=new User();
             List<User> userList = userService.getUserList();        

             model.addObject("user",user);
             model.addObject("userList",userList);
             return model;      
        }
```

Now this method will take you to the "userList" JSP, with your MODEL populated with "user" and "userList" attribute values.